# Is it possible to route specific paths of a Godaddy domain to a Wix Site and a Firebase Hosted Site?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a domain in Godaddy (xyz.com) and I have two hosted sites: (i) A Wix landing page and (ii) A Firebase Hosted site. What I want to do is route the base domain (xyz.com) to the Wix page and every url with path "xyz/username" to the firebase hosted site.

Currently, the Godaddy domain only routes to the Firebase hosted site.